# How to provide options to program with GDB?

Tags: c, gdb

I need to debug a program that requests some options.

This is not working:

```
$ gdb ./myprogram -option-to-program1 -option-to-program2
```

gdb writes an error: unrecognized option "-option-to-program1"

How to use it correctly?

Comment: run gdb with the program
`gdb ./myprogram`. When you get the gdb prompt type `run -option-to-program1 -option-to-program2 `

Comment: `gbb myprogram` , then `run arg1 arg2`

Comment: @debido `./` is not needed